# Facebook see who took my quiz

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our client would like to have a simple quiz that everyone can take, and if the user want, they can share the result on Facebook. Pretty much similar like this: http://www.whichblankareyou.com/q/which-alcoholic-drink-are-you

The only thing is; the client thought of randomly giving away a price to one of the users who shared their results on Facebook, this to encourage more people to really share their result (and thus generating more 'buzz' on Facebook about it)

Is it possible to do this? and if so: how ?

Comment: Of course you can post stories on facebook. You gotta search on google first!

Comment: yes, this I know. but is it possible to see WHO posted on facebook? I need to randomly pick one person out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your user posts a story a `post_id` is returned by the facebook and this is of the form-

> `userid_postid`

So, you can fetch the id before `_` and that will be the id of the user who shared the story.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but it doesn't work:

$result = $facebook->api('/me/links', 'post', $parameters);

it gets posted, but in $result I see only:

 array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(15) "844584742222729"
}

and no user id

Comment: Instead of `/me/links` use `/me/feed` for post!

Comment: if I use /me/feed then it doesn't show up on my friends notification feed